# Rcpp function crashes

Tags: r, rcpp

### My problem:

I am using R.3.0.1 together with RStudio 0.97.551 on a 64bit Windows7 PC and I have begun to outsource a function to C/C++ using Rcpp. The function compiles, but evaluating it within an R function produces a runtime error. I am not able to find out why and how to fix this.

### Details

Below is my cpp-file... let's say it's called "vector.cpp"

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector l5(double z, double k, double s, double K, double theta, double x, double h, NumericVector m){
    int n = m.size();
    NumericVector a(n);
    NumericVector bu(n);
    NumericVector b(n);
    NumericVector c(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n+1; i++){
        a[i] = pow(z,m[i]) * (pow((x*pow(h,m[i])/K), theta) - 1) * (K/theta);
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
            bu[i] += pow(z,j) * (1 - z) * fmax(((pow((s/K), theta) - 1) * (K/theta)), ((pow((x*pow(h, j)/K), theta) - 1) * (K/theta)));
        }
        b[i] = k *bu[i];
        c[i] = k * pow(z, m[i]) * fmax(((pow((s/K), theta) - 1) * (K/theta)), ((pow((x*pow(h, m[i])/K), theta) - 1) * (K/theta)));
    }

    return wrap(a-b-c);
}
```

which I compile in R (or RStudio) using the command

```
sourceCpp(<path to file>/vector.cpp)
```

It compiles - so far so good. However, when I go on to use the function l5 within other R functions it often leads R to crash (both in RStudio and the plain R GUI). In fact, also evaluating it itself isn't any more stable. To reproduce this, e.g. try evaluating l6 multiple times

```
l6 <- function(zs, ks, ss, Ks, thetas, xs, hs){
    z=zs
    k=ks
    s=ss
    K=Ks
    theta=thetas
    x=xs
    h=hs
    m=0:30
    res <- l5(z, k, s, K, theta,x, h, m)
return(res)
}
```

and run

```
l6(0.9, 0.1, 67, 40, 0.5, 44, 1.06)
```

Specifically, it produces the following runtime error

```
This application has requested Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
```

So what is wrong with my function?

### Solution

As Dirk suggested below there is an elementary mistake in the for loop, where i runs from 0 to n and thus has n+1 elements, but I intialized only vectors of length n. To avoid this mistake I now implemented the function using iterators

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector l5(double z, double k, double s, double K, double theta, double x, double h, NumericVector m){
    int n = m.size();
    NumericVector a(n);
    NumericVector bu(n);
    NumericVector b(n);
    NumericVector c(n);
    for(NumericVector::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i){
        a[*i] = pow(z, m[*i]) * (pow((x*pow(h, m[*i])/K), theta) - 1) * (K/theta);
        for(int j=0; j<*i; j++){
            bu[*i] += pow(z,j) * (1 - z) * fmax(((pow((s/K), theta) - 1) * (K/theta)), ((pow((x*pow(h, j)/K), theta) - 1) * (K/theta)));
        }
        b[*i] = k *bu[*i];
        c[*i] = k * pow(z, m[*i]) * fmax(((pow((s/K), theta) - 1) * (K/theta)), ((pow((x*pow(h, m[*i])/K), theta) - 1) * (K/theta)));
    }

    return wrap(a-b-c);
}
```

Many thanks again!

Comment: Iterator solution is an interesting idea. I would just have changed to `for (int i=0; i<n; i++)` which may be the most-widely used line in all of C and C++.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are making an elementary C/C++ error:

```
for(int i=0; i<n+1; i++)
```

will be accessed `n+1` times, but you allocated `n` spaces.

Comment: That moment when Dirk solves your problem within the blink of an eye, after you had been staring at it for a day... but yeah, thanks! Maybe a good example for why using iterators is a good idea. Would love to vote this up, but below 15 reputation =)

Comment: You can accept it, though, as the original question asker. Which in itself will increase your reputation.